# Convert multiple Java Beans to JSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have multiple Java bean classes that are associated to each other (JSON Array + JSON Object) since they have a nested structure.
There are about 10 classes. Is there a way to collectively convert these classes or at-least one by one?
I had created these classes out of a JSON data which I don't have access to right now.
So, now, what I'm looking forward is to create a dummy JSON out of those classes.
Using `GSON`, I tried converting one of these Bean classes however, I got an empty result. Here is one of the beans called `Attachment.java`.

**`Attachment.java`**

```
package mypackagename;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Attachment  implements Serializable{


    private Payload payload;

    private String type;

    public Payload getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }

    public void setPayload(Payload payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

***Implementation***

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
String json = gson.toJson(attachment);
```

[image]

Comment: This section of the Gson User Guide: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Finer-Points-with-Objects

The fourth bullet point explains how null fields are handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you got an empty result. Because your JSON object is empty. You should add data to your object and test it again as below:

```
Attachment attachment = new Attachment(new Payload("Test Payload"), "Test attachment");
String json = new Gson().toJson(attachment);
Log.e("Test", "Json: " + json); // result: Json: {"payload":{"test":"Test Payload"},"type":"Test attachment"}
```

To avoid empty object, you have to set a default value to your `payload` and `type` becaus Gson will ignore any null value.

Answer (score 0):

This section of the Gson User Guide: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Finer-Points-with-Objects

The fourth bullet point explains how null fields are handled.